# Custom git pre-receive hook possible on Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, githooks

I'm looking to add a custom guard to a Heroku application that blocks a push to my app's `master` branch from any other branch except `master` on a developer's local machine, but I don't see anything in the Heroku documentation for accessing the pre-receive hook. Does anyone know whether this is even possible to access, or if there's some other configuration or add-on that will offer me the same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Heroku does use its own pre-receive hook (as [illustrated here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/heroku-push-rejected)), and only mention a "[deploy hook](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks)", you would need to either:

- push to an intermediate repo that you control,n in order to put a pre-receive hook there: if that passes, that same hook can then push to the actual heroku remote repo. That is the gate repo strategy.
- or use a pre-commit hook (which is less convenient, as it needs to be deployed in all developers repos)

Comment: I suspected as much. Maybe the support team can do a one-off for me.